# Alter session with native query for a single JPA query

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm forced to use a certain NLS_LANGUAGE for accessing a database and don't want to change user.locale to avoid affecting the rest of the application. Is something like this okay to do or can it cause unexpected issues?

Also, how large is the scope of the session? Will this affect this single query only, or each call using the same entityManager, or even the whole application?

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class myDAOImpl implements MyDAO{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyUnit" )
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<Object> getSomeData(){
        em.createNativeQuery("alter session set nls_language = 'AMERICAN'").executeUpdate();    
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from my_view");
        return q.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a different `nls_language` for one query ? maybe it's something that can be solved within the query, ie with `to_char` function

Comment: If nls_language is not set to 'AMERICAN', a suboptimal execution plan is executed on the db, causing it to hang forever. Certain indexes will be ignored I've heard. Crazy design, i know, but it's outside my power to change anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter session on oracle will affect all future requests on that connection. So if you are using a connection-pool, as you should, this will affect all future sessions that are opened on the same connection.

Comment: How will this work with an EntityManager? Is it a pool in itself?

Comment: EntityManager is just JPA's Session equivalent class that is internally implemented by various JPA implementations to provide functionality. Hibernate actually uses the Session to back the EntityManager. The EntityManager itself keeps no pool. In JPA, you would configure this in persistence.xml or programmatically (or via Spring). The pool is a lower level concept. EntityManager works at a higher level.

Comment: So how does it work with default settings? How many session would a single entity manager handle? 1 or many? If there are multiple instances of MyDao pooled as EJBs, is it possible that sessions are shared through those instances?

Comment: The Hibernate Session object is just an implementation of EntityManager. Each EntityManager instance that is accessed in its own thread corresponds to one connection to the database (one database session). The database connection is never closed if you have a connection pool. The transactions are simply committed/rolled-back etc.

Comment: Does that mean that if I alter the session once per MyDAO instance, the setting will stay there until the JVM dies?

Comment: If you are using a connection pool, then yes. You should be able to verify this by monitoring SQL statements on the Oracle side.